# How can I find the content of a <p> tag using BeautifulSoup4? .content and .string did not work for this tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been experimenting with BeautifulSoup4 in Python with webscraping, and I am having trouble finding the content of a certain

tag since it is formatted differently than normal.

Here is a picture of the tag in question: 
[image: HTML Tag]

I've been able to locate the `<p>` tag fine using `tag = soup.find('p', attrs={'class':'uppercase', 'data-message-lang-key':'statusMessageKey'})` but I am having trouble finding the actual content of the tag where it says "Sale has started...".  So far, `tag.content`, `tag.string`, and `tag.child` all returned `None`.

How can I find this part of the tag using BS4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking for is `tag.get_text()`.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Didn’t fix the problem but thanks anyway, I think I know why though.  When I printed out the text of the GET request I used to find this, the text if the <p> tag wasn’t even there.